# React Project errors in production only

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm encountering a couple of strange errors when trying to deploy my React app. Everything works fine on a webpack dev server, but when I run it with production settings and having Express serve the index.html file like so:

```
// Production settings
app.use('/api/', routes)
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});
```

I get errors `undefined "parsererror" "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"` and `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

Some of the data being pulled from the server is appearing, and some is not. Almost all project code remains the same.

Comment: This is very vague, could you bring more details? the content of index, which library are you using, the line of the error. Help us to help you

Comment: I know, sorry. The line doesn't appear in the error. It says index.js 34505 but when I click it, nothing's there

Comment: No problem man. You are requesting a json file or index.html?

Comment: Well index.html loads in the browser correctly, but not the json data